# Visual Studio JavaScript debugging extremely slow

Tags: javascript, debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, performance

I am having the strangest problem debugging JavaScript in Internet Explorer in Visual Studio.

If I set a breakpoint in JavaScript code and run the (ASP.NET MVC) project in debug mode, I hit the break point fine. But shortly after that, while on the breakpoint, pretty much my whole computer locks up for 10-30 seconds. During this time I can move the mouse pointer, but not interact with anything. If I click on things eventually the computer starts to beep. 
After the 10-30 seconds is up everything is back to normal.

Debugging worked fine up until a couple of days ago. The same behavior is shown by different ASP.NET MVC projects.
I am running Internet Explorer 10 and Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 Enterprise 64 bit.
I have no third party antivirus (Only Windows Defender). I do not have intellitrace. I have only a single breakpoint, all others are deleted. I have tried deleting my .suo file.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I'm having the exact same problem on 3 different computers. The things they have in common is: Windows 8 64bit, Visual Studio 2012 (everything up to date with all latest official patches/updates), ReSharper 7.1.1000.900, Telerik Phone RAD Controls, DevExpress DXtreme 12.latest, Git Source Control Provider. I haven't started to eliminate any of the plugins yet.

Comment: I had the same problem. Morover, ctrl+K+D also works so slowly. In your code there should be a syntax error. For example I had a problem with json. [{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},]. there was a (,) at the end of the json more then needed. It slows down the visual studio. You probably have a syntax problem.

Comment: This isn't an answer to how to fix VS so the freezing doesn't occur, but no web developer who knows what he's doing would ever recommend VS as an editor. Since I don't just want to provide a problem but a solution as well, I think you should really check out two very very nice editors for windows. The first is [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), and the second is [Web Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). Good Luck on whatever you choose, and if you stick with VS, hope you get a valid answer!

Comment: I no longer work with this environment, and I can no longer reproduce the problem. Please note though, that the problem was not just the browser or VS hanging, it was *the whole operating system*. Everything became non-responsive.

Answer (score 0):

My browser (ff) locks up on me when a script on a website is taking too long to run typically.  It then throws a stop script prompt.  The fact that you can replicate it across three computers makes sense if it's the same erroneous script causing the lock up.  I doubt it'll matter if you try it on a win 7 box, win xp, but those are obvious tests if you're thinking sys configuration as a cause.  Also, try setting your breakpoint earlier in the script to tell what/when is locking up.

On a different note, I've always debugged javascript in firefox with firebug with great success.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turned out it was Intellisense. Intellisense chokes on large Javascript files. The slowdowns would happen even when I wasn't doing something that required Intellisense.

I ended up splitting them out and referencing the other files with:

```
/// <reference path="/scripts/<other>.js" />
```

This allowed autocomplete to work across files and prevented the lockups.